# What is the purpose of StatementWithEmptyBody?

Tags: android, suppress-warnings

when I created the drawer bar in Android Studio for my project, in the code for the select items put the next:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
```

But what is the use of this annotation?

Comment: Its just indicate empty block of code ,just like your methods is empty , no use of that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Warning itself explains meaning.

return type of `onNavigationItemSelected` is `boolean.` and we need to return any `boolean` value.

If there is `if` condition in `onNavigationItemSelected` and not returned then `@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")` need to add.

**Example:**

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.xyz) {
       // you should return boolean value here.
    }
    return false;
}
```

In example we are returning `false` by-default. and we haven't return any value in

**`if (id == R.id.xyz)`** condition.

You can clearly have a look at warning.

[image: suppress warning]

Comment: But what happens if you not put the annotation, can fail the app?

Comment: Of course not. it's just warning same as other warnings.

Comment: `boolean` and `Boolean` are different types in Java. This function should return a `boolean`. This answer incorrectly states that this function should return a `Boolean`.

Comment: @pts, mistake corrected. thanks for drawing attention.

Answer (score 4):

In case, if you have not inserted any code in that method, the annotation will make sure that no warnings are generated for that method.

Comment: But is a function with return value, if the body is empty, appear a error for no return

Comment: The method is generated when You added the drawer bar, which is a default method. Once you start adding options in your Menu Item to the Menu, only then it will generate any error.

Answer (score 3):

When you have a statement with no code inside of the curly brackets, Android Studio will give a warning about this. The annotation suppresses this warning in method having this annotation.

Example of statement with empty body (the body of the "else" part is empty):

```
if (something) {
    doThis();
} else {

}
```

These warnings are useful to let you double check if you didn't forget to code something. Only turn them off (with the annotation) when you have a good reason to do so.